# MariaDB/MySQL select query replace json array of ids into concatenated values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm not too familiar with database queries, but I would like to do the following: in a table, I have stored a column of tag ids like: `[1,6,8]` and I wish to return `"Music, Dance, Pop"` for example in my select query.

**I did not design the database schema, and I'm not allowed to modify it.**

The reason I would like to do so is the response of this query would be directly sent to the client for table rendering, and with the current ORM retrieval (PHP Laravel), this takes a long time retrieving the same related model for every row. **So I would like to know if a query like this would be possible.**

My schema looks something like this:

#### posts

```
id | name | ... | tag_ids (JSON array) | ...
```

#### tags

```
id | name
```

I have thought of using `JSON_REPLACE`, but have no idea on how to approach this problem at all. Is this even possible in plain SQL without code to post process the results?

Comment: You need to use a linking table for the tags. That would make things alot easier.Like: Genres (id, name) and Tags (genre_id, tag)

Comment: @Alphastrick Well, personally I wouldn't design the tables like this, but well, this exists and I had to work around it...

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) helps you then

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: @Nick I'm seeing this:  5.5.5-10.3.16-MariaDB-log as the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I'm not allowed to modify it

Ideally, you might to consider normalizing your data, which would make it easier to handle this problem.  That being said, with the help of the JSON functions we can try a join combined with an aggregation:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS tag_names
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN tags t
    ON JSON_SEARCH(p.tag_ids, 'one', t.id) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    p.id,
    p.name;
```

### Demo

Comment: Amazing! It's like total magic. I've never thought that joining and the `JSON_SEARCH` function can be used this way. I've learnt a lot. Thanks

Comment: In reality, the table has several of these columns. I've tested them but MaiaDB refused to group multiple of them: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=7607eceed5f301c5032ae8d42fba1b09 Anyway to fix this?

Comment: @Danilel You should open a new question if you have a follow-up.