# Laravel Query Builder express JSON join is not null

Tags: laravel

I have the following SQL, and couldn't insert into Laravel's builder:

```sql
LEFT JOIN members ON JSON_SEARCH(places.member_ids, 'one', members.id) IS NOT NULL
```

I tried:

```php
->leftJoin("members", DB::raw("JSON_SEARCH(places.member_ids, 'one', members.id)"), "is", DB::raw("not null"))
```

But the generated SQL kept becoming:

```sql
left join `members` on JSON_SEARCH(places.member_ids, 'one', members.id) = `is`
```

How can I do joining on JSON is not null?

---

#### EDIT

I found a mitigation for my case. I'm not sure why it works but it works.

```php
->leftJoin("members", DB::raw("JSON_SEARCH(places.member_ids, 'one', members.id)"), "!=", DB::raw("''"))
```

Comment: Is it really a left join if you do not allow joining null? From the source code of the query builder and join clause, I'm quite sure what you want to do is not possible. You might be more successful joining a sub query though.

Comment: @Namoshek I'm not exactly fluent in SQL, but I came from my previous question where I wanted to do something like this. There's even a demo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519025/mariadb-mysql-select-query-replace-json-array-of-ids-into-concatenated-values/57519178?noredirect=1#comment101506732_57519178

Answer (score 0):

I created an [updated version of the dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=88b1169a8e2ca7e51bb7eeaf8b31dbff) of your previous question. You basically should be able to use a normal `join($table)` together with a `whereNotNull($constraint)`:

```
->join('members')
->whereNotNull(DB::raw("JSON_SEARCH(places.member_ids, 'one', members.id)"))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But well, I needed that left join though. Because I still needed to show posts when there are no tags for the post.

Comment: Alright, in this case you really need to join, yep.